# How to redirect screen display to rs232 in Linux?

Tags: linux, console, serial

I need to redirect all Linux output to rs232 port in order to connect to it via console cable or via ssh or telnet.

How to do that? Is it possible to do that wihtout recompiling the kernel?

Comment: Search the interwebs for 'serial console linux'.  You'll find more tutorials on the subject than you could ever possibly read in one lifetime.

Comment: Are you wanting the kernel messages, the init messages, or just a login prompt?

Comment: Yes I want all output in the serial port (kernal messages, init messages and login prompt)

Comment: In order to actually answer this, we'd need to know which platform you're using (the exact kernel command line, assuming that serial console support has been included, depends on the platform somewhat). So, is this a RaspBerry Pi maybe? Or some other development plank device? A traditional X86-PC?

Comment: a traditional x86 PC